# MediaPlayer custom stream source

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

I’m developing an UWP app that should be able to play videos transferred through a custom TCP protocol implementation. 
Videos are MP4, so there’s no need to decode frames. 
My current solution is to download the file first, and then allow the user to play it, but with big files this is quite annoying. 
As a workaround I tried to implement `IRandomAccessStream` to feed the `MediaPlayer` while the file gets downloaded, but this isn’t a good solution for sure as there’s no buffering (and the video is just laggy on bad networks) nor visual download progress in the `TransportControls`. 
I know it is possible to create a custom `MediaStreamSource`, but it requires known encoding properties to be created and anyway it sounds like an overkill to have to decode frames by myself to feed it.

So I’m wondering if there’s any solution to my problem.

Comment: Laggy networks is a fact of life.  It is normally solved by having the video available in different formats, dynamically switching between them when the network starts getting pokey.  Called "adaptive streaming", the dedicated MSDN page [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming).

Comment: It's a bit different. If you stream some video over http the player is able to buffer it and to play it when enough data is ready. Faking an offline stream this won't happen.
I know what adaptive streaming is, and as I said I'm not using HTTP to receive video data.

Comment: Have you checked this document [Writing a Custom Media Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/writing-a-custom-media-source)?

Comment: @Bite Yes, as I mentioned in the question. However doesn’t seem to fit my needs as “to create the presentation descriptor, you must know the number of streams in the source content, and the possible formats of each stream”. Also using a MediaStreamSource requires to manually decode all the video samples, and it feels like an overkill to me :/

Comment: @FelaAmeghino Why not use HLS or DASH where the MP4 would be broken up into smaller fragments and a manifest could then determine where to grab the segments?  Did you have explored this as a possible option?